# In RViz and Gazebo, STL is displaced

Tags: ros2, gazebo-simu, rviz

I am following ROS2 example for robotic arm.
The arm has couple of parts, represented by STL.
Now, when I use the STL file that comes with [the example](https://github.com/dvalenciar/robotic_arm_environment), the arm is perfectly aligned.
But when I use Tinkercad ([tinkercad.com](https://tinkercad.com)), which is probably the best and definitely most popular of STL editors, the base I created becomes displaced:

[image]

The picture is for RViz, same in Gazebo.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found :) that Tinkercad saves selected STL WITH its on-grid coordinates, at least Z coordinate. In other words, before saving STL in Tinkercad, place it to 0,0,0. Very strange.